# Cómo interpolar una imagen como matriz?

Tags: java, imagen, matrices, inteligencia-artificial

Cuál es el método para interpolar una imagen al doble? El método recibe una matriz de N x N y retorna una matriz de 2N X 2N. :3 aiuda

```
   package Modelacion;
   
   public class Operadores {
   
       private short matrizGris[][]; public short [][] OperadorInterpolacion (short [][] matrizGris){
           for (int i = 0; i < matrizGris.length; i++) {
               for (int j = 0; j < matrizGris[i].length; j++) {
                   
               }
           }
           return null;
       }    }
```

todo esta hecho mediante controlador

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Comment: ninguno quiero saber cual es el método para interpolar la imagen, como referencia me dieron eso                                                                           Píxel p con coordenadas (x,y)                                                           
Vecindad-4                                                                                                
V4(p) = { (x+1,y), (x-1,y), (x,y+1), (x,y-1) }                 
VD(p) = { (x+1,y+1), (x-1,y-1), (x-1,y+1), (x+1,y-1) }

Comment: y esto Vecindad-8                                                                                                
V8(p) = { V4(p) ∪VD(p) }

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo lo que te dieron como referencia. Pero la idea es sencilla, cada punto en la entrada se convierte en 4 en la salida

```
ab -> aabb
      aabb
```

Un array (matriz) 1x2 se convierte en 2x4.

```
salida[x*2][y*2] = entrada[x][y]
salida[x*2+1][y*2] = entrada[x][y]
etc...
```

La clave esta en el `[x*2][y*2]`